# Нумерация в range-based цикле для массива

Tags: c++, c++11

Код:

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (auto i: arr) std::cout << "i" << "\n";
```

Вопрос, почему нумерация идет с единицы, а не с нуля? Как-то это неправильно выглядит, не говоря уже о том что цикл уходит за пределы массива. Как использовать range-based цикл для массива чтобы нумерация была с нуля, а не с единицы?

Comment: Ваш цикл перебирает элементы массива, элемент с нулевым индексом имеет значение 1, которое вы видите на выходе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструкция `for (auto i: container)` поочередно перебирает **элементы** контейнера, а не индексы, и применима даже там, где нет понятия индекса - например, в хеш-таблице.

Это выражение можно рассматривать как разворачивающееся в

```
for(auto iterator = begin(container); iterator != end(container); ++iterator)
{
    auto i = *iterator;
```

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я ступил. Привык к оригинальным циклам, даже не подумал что может быть как-то иначе.